# How do I 'down grade' to python2.7

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib

Being quite cavalier I went for the latest version of Python (3.2.2) 
Unfortunately it lacks the matplotlib that I desperately need. 
I have downloaded python 2.7. 
My simple question is weather I have to uninstall python3.2 or can I leave it on my windows 64 system?

Answer (score 3):

you can keep the python 3.2 installation, but you will have to be carefull about which version you launch (by making the call explicit). you can always check the python version in a script by doing:

```
import sys
print sys.version
```

If you have no particular use of python 3.2, I recommend uninstalling it.

Comment: the being careful part has to do with the path environment for the python executables. As Simon said, unless you need 3.2, it's best to uninstall

Comment: Excellent. Uninstalled it - 2.7 works great! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a difference on python in windows but on mac and linux I simply call older versions using

```
python2.6 or python2.7
```

It seems to keep all the versions I previously had before.  Maybe try running the above command and seeing if it works on windows and if it does just change the symbolic link 'python' is pointing to.